# Liferay user import on login causes UserScreenNameException

Tags: java, import, ldap, liferay, single-sign-on

I am documenting this here to help other people with the same problem.

Liferay user import on login caused UserScreenNameException. Thanks to a colleague, we found this to be caused by special characters in the user's screen name like underscores etc.. Since this was a valid use case, we had to find a way allow the special characters. Liferay by default does not allow special characters in screen name.

Once we added the following property to the portal-ext.properties file, there were no more errors and users got imported properly.

`#Property to try to allow special characters in screen name
users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LiberalScreenNameValidator`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It it exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my question in the question itself.

Once we added the following property to the portal-ext.properties file, there were no more errors and users got imported properly.

`#Property to try to allow special characters in screen name users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LiberalScreenNameValidator`

Hope this helps someone.